Tabulator - Child Rows Not Dynamically Updating When Toggled
I’m trying to implement expandable child rows in Tabulator, where each row can have nested child rows that are toggled with a button. The child rows are correctly hidden by default and revealed when the "Show Children" button is clicked, but the layout doesn't update dynamically when child rows are toggled, unless I manually scroll or resize the window.
Steps to reproduce:
I've set up a parent table where each row can have child rows (nested data).
The child rows are initially hidden.
When I click the "Show Children" button, a child table should be dynamically appended below the parent row, and its visibility should toggle.
The issue:
The child rows toggle visibility correctly when clicked, but the table doesn’t update its layout (e.g., row heights or overall layout) until I manually scroll or resize the window.
I’ve tried using table.redraw(true) and resize() methods, but they haven’t solved the problem.
My current code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tabulator - Expandable Child Rows</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.4.3/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Tabulator with Expandable Child Rows</h1>
  <div id="example-table"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Sample Data
    const tableData = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Parent 1",
        age: 40,
        children: [{
            id: 11,
            name: "Child 1.1",
            age: 10
          },
          {
            id: 12,
            name: "Child 1.2",
            age: 12
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Parent 2",
        age: 35,
        children: [{
            id: 21,
            name: "Child 2.1",
            age: 8
          },
          {
            id: 22,
            name: "Child 2.2",
            age: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Parent 3",
        age: 50,
        children: [{
          id: 31,
          name: "Child 3.1",
          age: 15
        }]
      }
    ];

    // Initialize main Tabulator table
    const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
      data: tableData, // Parent data
      layout: "fitColumns",
      columns: [{
          title: "Name",
          field: "name",
          sorter: "string",
          width: 200
        },
        {
          title: "Age",
          field: "age",
          sorter: "number",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          title: "Children",
          field: "children",
          formatter: (cell, formatterParams) => {
            const children = cell.getValue();
            return children && children.length > 0 ?
              `<button class="toggle-child">Show Children (${children.length})</button>` :
              "No Children";
          },
          cellClick: (e, cell) => {
            const children = cell.getValue();
            if (children && children.length > 0) {
              const parentElement = cell.getElement();
              const toggleButton = parentElement.querySelector(".toggle-child");
              let childContainer = parentElement.querySelector(".child-table-container");

              if (!childContainer) {
                // Create the child table
                childContainer = createChildTable(cell, children);
                parentElement.appendChild(childContainer);
              }

              // Toggle visibility
              if (childContainer.style.display === "none" || !childContainer.style.display) {
                childContainer.style.display = "block";
                toggleButton.textContent = `Hide Children`;
              } else {
                childContainer.style.display = "none";
                toggleButton.textContent = `Show Children (${children.length})`;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    // Create a child table dynamically
    const createChildTable = (parentCell, children) => {
      const container = document.createElement("div");
      container.className = "child-table-container";
      container.style.display = "none"; // Initially hidden
      const childTable = new Tabulator(container, {
        data: children, // Child data
        layout: "fitColumns",
        columns: [{
            title: "Name",
            field: "name",
            sorter: "string",
            width: 150
          },
          {
            title: "Age",
            field: "age",
            sorter: "number",
            width: 100
          }
        ],
        movableColumns: true,
        height: "150px"
      });

      return container;
    };
  </script>

  <style>
    .child-table-container {
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: none;
      /* Initially hidden */
    }

    .toggle-child {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: blue;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>



What I’ve tried:

table.redraw(true) to force a redraw after toggling child rows.
resize() method to try to trigger a layout update.
Various DOM manipulations like appending elements and toggling visibility.
However, none of these methods seem to update the layout correctly.

My question:
How can I ensure that the table layout updates properly when toggling child rows in Tabulator? Is there a more appropriate way to handle dynamic updates to the table when child rows are shown or hidden?
